# Deleting data directly from backup file

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2014

Is it possible to update the data directly inside the backup file (*.bak) in SQL Server 2014?

The scenario is that I want to automate the process of providing the "smaller" database to some endusers/developers (just deleting some rows/updating values in column) to be restored by them furthermore. Can I achieve this goal by running any command to directly update the *.bak ... or I have to prepare additional (copy of) database, then restore it from this *.bak, then provide my "cleaning" (running update command) and then prepare different *.bak file again?

Answer (score 1):

Restore it to a dummy DB, purge the data that you don't want them to have, make another full backup, drop the dummy DB, and then provide them the copy of the BAK file at that point.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of script can be easily run automatically:

```
USE [master]
GO
BACKUP DATABASE [Test] TO  DISK = N'C:\...\Backup\Test.bak' 
WITH  COPY_ONLY, NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'Test-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
RESTORE DATABASE [Test_Dev] FROM  DISK = N'C:\...\Backup\Test.bak' 
WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'Test' TO N'C:\...\DATA\Test_dev.mdf'
,  MOVE N'Test_log' TO N'C:\...\LOGS\Test_dev_log.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5
GO

USE [Test_Dev]
GO
Delete From XXX
Delete From YYY
GO

USE [master]
GO
BACKUP DATABASE [Test_dev] TO  DISK = N'C:\DB\...\Backup\Test_dev.bak' 
WITH  COPY_ONLY, NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'Test-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
DROP DATABASE [Test_Dev]
GO
```

You can use dynamic SQL if you need a more generic script.